# How to format Django templates without having formatting white-space in the output?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to generate some txt files and Jinja2 used for Django templates causes the template code to look really messy, because I cannot use line-breaks without having them in the generated result. The `{% spaceless %}` tags would probably make things only messier as it will be hard to insert the wanted space.

An example:

```
[{% if foo.condition %}x{% else %} {% endif %}] List of requirements fulfilled: {{ foo.requirements_fullfilled }} of {{ foo.num_requirements }} {% for requirement in foo.requirement %}
- {{ requirement.number }}{% if requirement.name %}: {{ solution.exercise.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Note the linebreak before `-` which makes the list add a linebreak before each bullet point and the missing linebreaks for all other tags, as they would be visible in the output.

Using spaceless would allow for formatting, but also remove the linebreak before the bullet points. Without spaceless the line looks quite messy. I also tried to use `{# #}` with a linebreak inside the comment as workaround, but multi-line comments need to use the `{% comment %}` template tag, which itself has a quite verbose name and would result in, for example:

```
[{% if foo.condition %}{% comment %}
    {% endcomment %}x{% comment %}
{% endcomment %}{% else %}{% comment %}
    {% endcomment %} {% comment %}{# Attention: Here is a space character between the comment tags! #}
{% endcomment %}{% endif %}]
```

And that's just the part for generating a space or an `x`. Of course, I could write here an "x if true" filter, but this would not help with the rest of the long line.

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic out of the template into the Python view. Using Class-based views, you could do

```
def get_context_data( self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs)

    context['foocon'] = "x" if foo.condition else " "

    req_texts = []
    for requirement in foo.requirement:

        name = f": {solution.exercise.name}" if requirement.name else ""
        req_texts.append(
            f"- {requirement.number}{name}" )

    context['req_text'] = '\n'.join(req_texts)
    return context
```

And then the template becomes

```
[{{foocon}}] List of requirements fulfilled: {{ foo.requirements_fullfilled }} of {{ foo.num_requirements }} 
{{req_text}}
```

Or you could do a bit more work in Python and simply substitute one variable with no logic in the template at all.

Depending on the rest of the template and requirements  I might dispense with rendering entirely and simply build up a set of text lines as a Python list of strings, then return it as a text response

```
filename = "some-filename.txt"
response = HttpResponse(
      '\n'.join( list_of_lines), 
       content_type='text/plain'
)
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
return response
```

Comment: The problem is, that for more logic (I have quite a few conditional lines, which need an `{% if something %}` on the previous line) this approach also becomes cumbersome as it is in the end a long list of `result += "something"` operations which usually would be better replaced by using templates.

Comment: I guess I prefer reading Python to Django Template language as soon as the logic becomes non-trivial, and especially if whitespace becomes significant. YMMV.

Comment: You might get a bit of simplification using the Django built-in filter yesno provided you don't want to conditionally generate any commas.`{{foo.condition|yesno:"x, "}}` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno